# How to click a button element on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created 5 buttons. I'm loading some pages on button click. I want the first button automatically clicked on page load and load it's corresponding html file and the remaining buttons should load html files only on clicking them. Someone help me!!

This is my jquery:

```
$('a#Home').click(function() {
  $("#home").load("x.html");
});

$('a#Menu1').click(function() {
  $("#menu1").load("y.html");
});

$('a#Menu2').click(function() {
  $("#menu2").load("z.html");
});

$('a#Menu3').click(function() {
  $("#menu3").load("searcharray.html");
});

$('a#Menu4').click(function() {
  $("#menu4").load("sortarray.html");
});
```

Comment: `$('a#Home').trigger('click')` http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ however better use `$("#home").load("x.html");`

Comment: 1) Call `trigger('click')`, or `click()` on the required element 2) DRY up your code

Comment: `}).click();` can be used to click at page load.

Comment: Why don't you put the link on the href and trigger the Home button on load?

Comment: @toni plz test the ans that i given.

Comment: @toni have you tested my code?

Answer (score 1):

Just test this code. I think this will help you.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $('#btn1').trigger( "click" );
});
function fun1()
{
 alert('loaded');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn1" onclick="fun1()">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn1</button>
<button id="btn3">btn1</button>
<button id="btn4">btn1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first button is Home then you want run that on [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) by using `$(function()`

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a#Home').click();
    });

    function loadHome() {
        $("#home").load("x.html");
    };
</script>
```

Then update your link to be like:

```
<a id="Home" onclick="loadHome()">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: _I want the first button automatically clicked on page load_......Your code does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

trigger the event yourself:

```
$('a#Home').click(function() {
  $("#home").load("x.html");
});
$('a#home').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

## Theoretical answer

You can trigger any event on any element using the `.trigger()` method. This will require you to specify which event you want to fire. [More information.](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

It is also possible to trigger a click event just by calling `.click()` after binding the event handling. [The documentation shows us that we can use this function for both purposes.](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

`$( document ).ready()` is an interaction that can be used to run code once when the document has been loaded. [More info on that can be found here.](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

## Examples

Example #1 (using `.trigger()`)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a#Home').trigger('click');
});
```

Example #2 (using `.click()`)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a#Home').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 <script>
       function pageLoad()
{
    alert('hello');
}

pageLoad();

 </script>
```

```
<button id="btn1" onclick="pageLoad()">btn1</button>
```